# Clion all printf printed out below scanf when I am debuging

Tags: c, debugging, clion

When I simply run it in Clion, it works all right. While I am trying to debug it, it only `printf` after all the `scanf` is completed.

Below is a simple program to verify whether the array containing three values can add up to a target with either two of the three values.

This is the effect after debugging.
[image]

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int twoNums(int *nums, int numsSize, int target, int *returnSize);

int main() {
    system("chcp 65001");
    int string[3], target;
    int numsSize = 3;
    int isTrue;
    int *returnSize = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);

    printf("Please input the array to be queried：\n");
    scanf("[%d,%d,%d]", &string[0], &string[1], &string[2]);
    printf("Please input the target value：\n");
    scanf("%d", &target);
    isTrue = twoNums(string, numsSize, target, returnSize);
    if (isTrue)
        printf("indexs of these is (%d, %d)", returnSize[0], returnSize[1]);
    else
        printf("something went wrong!");
    free(returnSize);
}

int twoNums(int *nums, int numsSize, int target, int *returnSize) {
    int i, j, cnt;
    int flag = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {
        cnt = target - nums[i];
        for (j = i + 1; j < numsSize; j++) {
            if (nums[j] == cnt) {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 1)
            break;
    }
    if (flag == 1) {
        returnSize[0] = i;
        returnSize[1] = j;
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Why would this happen? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There is no guaranteed synchronization between standard input and output streams, and however your debugger works has boogered it from what you expect. Fix it by adding an `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf`.

Comment: So is there any need to release this code with so many `fflush(stdout)`s?

Comment: @TomZz: On most [platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform), writing `fflush( stdout );` when switching from output to input is not necessary. However, on very few, it is necessary. Therefore, it is usually not written, but it would be safer to write it. In your case, if the debugger you are using requires it, then I would write it, unless you are planning to switch to a different debugging environment.